# Change gridline colour or style in MS Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010, grid

How can I change the colour or style (solid line or dots, as in The Gimp) of the document gridlines shown using View > Gridlines (*not* table gridlines) in Microsoft Word 2010 or 2007?

I can change the grid spacing by Inserting a random shape, selecting the shape, then Format > Align > Grid Settings... > Grid settings (what were Microsoft thinking?!) but there is no option to change its colour or style.

The default colour is too dark and makes it difficult to see what I'm drawing.

I know I can use [Randy Reddig's QuickGamma](http://www.katsbits.com/files/QuickGamma_0.1.1.zip) to increase my monitor's gamma to lighten the lines, but that makes drawings and images too bright.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't change color or style with the Grid option, what you can do is set up the grid you want, save it as a .png, and then use it with the custom Watermark option at 100%. It's a workaround, but should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and workaround was I just draw a straight line using insert, shapes, select line. Colour the line and then align my text box to that line down the page.